# .Net Core on Linux runs fine with 'dotnet myapp.dll' but fails with systemctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to host an ASP.Net Core MVC application on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS by following the directions in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

From the Linux machine, I use `git pull` to pull in my project.  I build it successfully with `dotnet build`, which triggers a package restore.  I publish it successfully with `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64`.  I change directories to `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1` and run `sudo cp ./*.* /var/aspnetcore/myapp/` to copy the files into the directory where I am hosting the project.  I navigate to that directory and type `dotnet myapp.dll` - the app begins listening on ports 5000 and 5001, and from a different computer, I can type my domain name into a browser and see the web site, which means the Nginx reverse proxy and Kestrel must be working fine.

Now I want to run the application as a service so that it starts with the computer, restarts on crash, logs errors, etc, but when I type `sudo systemctl start kestrel-myapp.service` it crashes immediately and attempts to restart every 10 seconds but fails.  The log shows the error: `An assembly in the application dependencies manifest (myapp.deps.json) was not found: package: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design', version '1.1.5' path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design.dll' Main process exited, code=exited, status=140/n/a`

So, the version 1.1.5 looks suspiciously low, but I updated all of my NuGet packages and it still wants to use it.  Plus, I don't understand why it doesn't crash with `dotnet myapp.dll` if there is a problem with the dependencies.  Does anybody know how to fix the issue?

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp ASP.Net Core MVC Application

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/myapp/myapp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=myapp
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Bonus question: where do I copy my wwwroot folder with my static files to?  The application runs but can't find any of my javascript or css files, and I'm not sure where they belong.

Comment: By the way, the folder /lib/netstandard1.3 does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64` it creates several directories. You want to use the `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/linux-x64/publish` directory. Other directories contain builds too, but those builds assume they will be run on development systems. Only the `publish` directory contains bits that should be deployed. The other directories contain bits that assume they are running in a development environment.

It works when you run `dotnet myapp.dll` because you are still running as your regular user and it sees your local development assets, including the nuget cache.

When you run via `systemctl`, it runs as `root` which does not have any local nuget cache and can't use the development (non-`publish`ed) version of your code.

Comment: Yay!  There are a lot more files in /linux-x64/publish.  Thanks for the help!  Do you know if wwwroot can be copied into /var/aspnetcore/myapp, or where those files belong?  I am used to publishing from VS to IIS, which does all of that for you...

Comment: Reading the docs, `publish` should include `wwwroot` already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/directory-structure?view=aspnetcore-2.1. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: It does when I do it right... I was not using -a when copying, so I was not copying recursively.  That solved the problem.  Sorry, I know bash well enough to follow a tutorial, but I'm not very experienced with Linux.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the WorkingDirectory is set to the directory where the runtime dll file is located.